# Get Current Data on Update Page to Checkbox Form with Codeigniter 3 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, activerecord

I have a problem when showing current data on checkbox form and checked status in edit page.

This are my table on the database:

***data_access table***

[image: data_access table]

***users_data_access table***

[image: users_data_access table]

**This is my controller:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
  function update($id){
    $this->data['user']                 = $this->Auth_model->get_by_id($id);
    $this->data['get_all_data_access']  = $this->Dataaccess_model->get_all();

    $this->load->view('back/auth/user_edit', $this->data);
  }
}
```

**This is my model:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth_model extends CI_Model
{
  function get_by_id($id){
    $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
    return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
  }
}


<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dataaccess_model extends CI_Model
{
  function get_all(){
    return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
  }
}
```

**This is my view:**

```
<?php 
$this->db->where('user_id', $user->id_users);
$dataAccessOld = $this->db->get('users_data_access')->result();
print_r($dataAccessOld);

foreach ($get_all_data_access as $alldataAccess) {                      
  foreach($dataAccessOld as $oldDataAccess){
    if($oldDataAccess->data_access_id == $alldataAccess->id_data_access){
      $checked = 'checked';
    }else{$checked = '';}
  }
?>

<div class="pretty p-icon p-smooth">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data_access_id[]" value="<?php echo $alldataAccess->id_data_access ?>" <?php echo $checked ?>>
  <div class="state p-success">
    <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
    <label><?php echo $alldataAccess->data_access_name ?></label>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

From the script above, i want to match between from the data_access and users_data_access table when edit a data by user_id but it only show 1 data from all the checkbox. The result showed on picture below:

[image: the current output]

The result should be selected by from match the between data_access table and users_data_access table.

Any help will be so appreciated.

Comment: what you exactly want??

Comment: @KUMAR if a user have all data access (read, create, update, delete and restore) the checkbox should be checked, and if other user only have read and create data access so the checkbox only checked on read and create checkbox form, and so on for other users.

Comment: you are overwriting $checked in your loop, returning only the last value of the array